# How select record in browser window with mouse double click

Tags: .net

In a Data Browser like the one in the example, what do I have to do to be able to choose the highlighted record with a double click of the mouse as an alternative to choosing with the Default Button?
[Data browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l7c9.png)

I tried this code:

```
method MouseButtonDoubleClick(oMouseEvent) class ScegliSchBrowse
    local nButtonID as int
    nButtonID := IIf(oMouseEvent == NULL_OBJECT, 0, oMouseEvent:ButtonID)
    super:MouseButtonDoubleClick(oMouseEvent)
    self:Owner:ButtonOK() // Return choice code to the Owner
    return nil
```

but when double click nothing happens.